# XMPGPano meta data to image by C# : for facebook 360 image

Tags: c#, facebook, image, xmp

### I am making facebook 360 image by custom stitching using C#-emgu.

1. Can able to set EXIF tags(make & model) using C# image property items.

   ```
    // Sample code for set exif make tag

   var dummy1 = Image.FromFile(@"filePathName.jpg");
   PropertyItem pItem = dummy1.PropertyItems[0];
   string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pItem.Value);
   pItem.Id = 0x010F; // make tag id
   pItem.Type = 2;
   pItem.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("*****");
   pItem.Len = pItem.Value.Length;
   jpeg1.SetPropertyItem(pItem);
   ```
2. Cant able to set XMPGPano tags below listed by C#.

> [XMPGPano docs in google street view](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata#example_of_a_full_photo_sphere)
>
> ```
> * CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels (final image height)
> * CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels (final image width)
> * ProjectionType (equirectangular)
> * CroppedAreaLeftPixels (No idea what it is?)
> * CroppedAreaTopPixels (No idea what it is?)
> * FullPanoHeightPixels (No idea what it is?)
> * FullPanoWidthPixels (No idea what it is?)
> ```

[Image : Sample XMPGPano tags in exif tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtGhb.jpg)

3. But face book understand 360 image only if I add XMPGPano tags.

### Please route me following points below..

1. Why this below tags with sample calculations

   - CroppedAreaLeftPixels (No idea what it is?)
   - CroppedAreaTopPixels (No idea what it is?)
   - FullPanoHeightPixels (No idea what it is?)
   - FullPanoWidthPixels (No idea what it is?)
2. How to add this tags programmatically C#.