# Retrieving list of Tags from file properties

Tags: java, windows

I would like to retrieve the list of Tags attached to a file in Windows 7 programatically. I am trying to create a mapping of file->tags that I can move across different platforms.

Is anyone aware of a library, or a way to get the 'Tags' values from command line? So far I have only been able to find ways to get basic file attributes such as Author, Date Created, etc.

I am unable to load PowerShell scripts on the computer unfortunately so am not able to make use of those features.

I tried using 'UserDefinedFileAttributeView' but that did not return any values, like so:

```
   private LinkedList<String> windowsGetAllFileTags(File file) {

    UserDefinedFileAttributeView fileAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file.toPath().toAbsolutePath(), UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
    List<String> allAttributes = null;
    try {
        allAttributes = fileAttributeView.list();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(String attribute : allAttributes) {
        System.out.println("Attribute = " + attribute);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[An image of the Windows 7 Properties View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtnYz.png)

Comment: Why did you tag both `java` and `powershell`? What of both do you want?
Also please provide what you achived so far (post your code).

Comment: I was thinking a solution utilizing either or would be okay, but after looking into it I a not able to load scripts with PowerShell due to insufficient privilege. Will remove the tag.

Comment: I very much doubt that `Files.getFileAttributeView` is what you need. File attributes are stored alongside the file's directory entry. They are things like permissions and read-only flags. What you're after is metadata that is stored inside the contents of JPG and other types of media files. You'll need to look for a third-party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Java library written and called as `PE/COFF 4J` on [Github](https://github.com/kichik/pecoff4j).

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.boris.pecoff4j.PE;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.ResourceDirectory;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.ResourceEntry;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.constant.ResourceType;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.io.PEParser;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.io.ResourceParser;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.resources.StringFileInfo;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.resources.StringTable;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.resources.VersionInfo;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.util.ResourceHelper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PE pe = PEParser.parse("C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
        ResourceDirectory rd = pe.getImageData().getResourceTable();

        ResourceEntry[] entries = ResourceHelper.findResources(rd, ResourceType.VERSION_INFO);
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            byte[] data = entries[i].getData();
            VersionInfo version = ResourceParser.readVersionInfo(data);

            StringFileInfo strings = version.getStringFileInfo();
            StringTable table = strings.getTable(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < table.getCount(); j++) {
                String key = table.getString(j).getKey();
                String value = table.getString(j).getValue();
                System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Will print:

```
CompanyName = Microsoft Corporation
FileDescription = Notepad
FileVersion = 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
InternalName = Notepad
LegalCopyright = © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
OriginalFilename = NOTEPAD.EXE
ProductName = Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
ProductVersion = 6.1.7600.16385
```

---

If you mention of obtaining tags of images or videos, [@Drew Noakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24874/drew-noakes) has written Java library called as [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) for it.

> ```
> Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imagePath);
> ```
>
> To iterate all values in the file:
>
> ```
> for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
>     for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
>         System.out.println(tag);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You can also read specific values from specific directories:
>
> ```
> // obtain the Exif SubIFD directory
> ExifSubIFDDirectory directory 
>     = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);
>
> // query the datetime tag's value
> Date date = directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
> ```
>
> The library is available for Maven users too.

Comment: This is designed to work for executable images only. The OP seems to be asking about JPG, MP4 etc file types.

Comment: @snr Thank you! The metadata-extractor library has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows PowerShell, you could grab it with a bit of [help from `PresentationCore.dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280948/reading-data-metadata-from-jpeg-xmp-or-exif-in-c-sharp):

```
function Get-ImageTags {
  param(
    [string]$Path
  )

  Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore

  try {
    $FileStream = (Get-Item $Path).Open('Open','Read')
    $BitmapFrame = [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame]::Create($FileStream)
    $Tags = @($BitmapFrame.Metadata.Keywords |%{ $_ })
  }
  catch {
    throw
    return
  }
  finally {
    if($FileStream){
      $FileStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
  return $Tags
}
```

Then use like:

```
$Tags = Get-ImageTags -Path path\to\file.jpeg
```

The `$Tags` variable will now contain an array of tags

Comment: My mistake, I thought I would be able to use PowerShell but i am unable to load  ps files due to user restrictions.

Comment: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Answer (score 0):

what about [Files.getAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...))

I didn't tried that but probably this could work:
`Files.getAttribute(Paths.get("/some/dir","file.txt"), "description:tags")`

Comment: Unfortunately "description" is not a valid view, I will try to look for more examples - perhaps description is not the right name of the view problem.