Metadata modification for multiple file formats in C#
I am currently working on a .NET program for my friend who is a photographer, that will allow him to modify metadata of photos (mostly jpeg and RAW like cr3) to tag them and filter according to those tags.
Unfortunately i can't really find a somewhat universal way of reading and modifying metadata of different file formats. Do you know any way that could solve my problem? Should i write my own code that will read metadata for separate file formats?
All i could find were libraries that support only one type of data like EXIFLIB. Does that mean that every file format has it's unique way of storing metadata? Thanks for help!

You could use BitmapMetadata for the formats that have corresponding BitmapEncoder/BitmapDecoder, see derived classes. If you want library recommendations -> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

EXIF was created after most common formats. RAW isn't a single format either, it's how each camera vendor stores unprocessed data, in whatever way they want and is often subject to patents. So not only does every format have a unique way to store metadata, there's no common definition of "metadata". EXIF defines common tags but it's up to each format to store them.

Open source libraries like ImageSharp cover the most common formats, commercial libraries cover more formats, but the more obscure a format is, the harder it is to find support. An open source library can't support patented/licensed extensions because the camera vendor requires a license fee or may refuse to license them, requiring people to use their own software

See this answer for recommendation on
how to read out metadata from a file info object in C#. Yes, different image formats have different means of storing
image metadata. Note that bitmap images such as bmp, gif, tif and jpeg is supported. Raw needs special handling. Exif needs Libexif.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2281704
